# custom uiwindow iphone

Tags: iphone, uiwindow

I want to customize default UIWindow. My aim is that the first window should be of size 320,100 so when user launches the application then he will just see window of size 320width and 100height (0,200,320,100) while remaining screen will be transparent and user will see other applications through transparent screen.

please help me out.

Answer (score 1):

This is just not possible! Read some introduction stuff. Search for sandboxing for the reason why this does not work.